# Best practice: prepare props only once for rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-i18next

Consider the following simple page in a nextjs app:

```
type MyProps = {
    myData: string[]
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<MyProps> = async ({ req, res }) => {
    return { props: {myData: calcData()} }
}

function MyComponent(props: MyProps) {
   return <div>{props.myData}</div>
}
```

**What is the best practice to prepare data in props?** In my case I need to sort data according to a criteria that is not present on server-side code (current language in client-side browser, using next-i18next). I could use state like

```
function MyComponent(props: MyProps) {
   const [sortedProps] = useState({myData: props.myData.sort(...)})

   return <div>{sortedProps.myData}</div>
}
```

but that doesn't sound "intended by React" for me. Maybe `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` that runs once is a better choice? If yes, how do I remember the resulting data from `useEffect`? `useRef`?

EDIT: Or is `useMemo` the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lazy initial state as follows:-

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

Ref: `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state`

Comment: Alright, that's a good pointer. But is using state here a good practise?